# .vimrc auto command to add text when opening a new file

Tags: vim

Need to add an auto command to my .vimrc that automatically inserts text on the first line, it will be my shebang. I want to do this without redirecting to a skeleton text file.

I have seen this question asked before but the solution always seems to involve creating a skeleton text file and pulling from it. This seems overly complicated considering that I'm not looking for a full header.

I can't figure out why this won't work:

```
autocmd BufNewFile * let line = "#!/usr/bin/env" . (empty(&filetype) ? '' : ' '.&filetype)
```

Have also tried variant:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.* let line = "#!/usr/bin/env" . (empty(&filetype) ? '' : ' '.&filetype)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a substitution on the first line:

```
autocmd BufNewFile * let ftype = &ft | execute 'silent! 1s:.*:#!/usr/bin/env ' . ftype
```

Because shebangs are used in interpreted languages you could replace `BufNewFile *` with `BufNewFile *.sh,*.perl,*.py`. This prevents having shebangs in languages such as C.

Comment: It works! However, instead of "python" I get "py". Could this be a problem when I attempt to run the program?

Comment: Answer updated. I replaced `expand('%:e')` with a variable `ftype` containing the value of `&filetype`.

Comment: That works! In the end I used `autocmd BufNewFile * execute 'silent! 1s/.*/#!\/usr\/bin\/env ' . (empty(&filetype) ? '' : ' '.&filetype)`, which has the added benefit of checking for no file type and moving on